# is there a method to add harcoded value in sqlalchemy session query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to add a column in my query object in python with a hardcoded value.

code is mentioned below :

but I am getting an error that the cart accepted is not a column.

```
class FCD(PresentationUnified, TableDocMixin):
siteid = Column(BIGINT)
discountlevel = Column(String(512))
discounttype = Column(String(512))
discountid = Column(BIGINT)
cart_key = Column(String(512))
auditinfo__createdate = Column(TIMESTAMP)
auditinfo__updatedate = Column(TIMESTAMP)

PrimaryKeyConstraint(siteid
                     , name='siteid')

__tablename__ = 'FCD_Fact'


def __init__(self, schema=PresentationUnified.metadata.schema):
    self.__table__.schema = schema



def __source(self, session, schema):
    Cart(schema=schema)
    CartRejectedDiscounts(schema=schema)
    return session.query(Cart.siteid.label("siteid")
                           , 'Cart accepted'
                           , 'currency'
                           , CartRejectedDiscounts.discountid.label("discountid")
                           , Cart.auditinfo__createdate.label("auditinfo__createdate")
                           , Cart.auditinfo__updatedate.label("auditinfo__updatedate")
                           ).join(Cart, and_(CartRejectedDiscounts._sdc_source_key__id == Cart._id))
```

so how can I pass a hardcoded value in my final table?

I want sql generated to be like :

```sql
select Cart.siteid as siteid, 'Cart accepted' as discountlevel,
       'currency' as discounttype, 
       CartRejectedDiscounts.discountid as discountid,
       Cart.auditinfo__createdate as auditinfo__createdate, 
       Cart.auditinfo__updatedate as auditinfo__updatedate 
from CartRejectedDiscounts 
join Cart 
  ON CartRejectedDiscounts._sdc_source_key__id == Cart._id
```

Comment: Can u write the equivalent sql query in your question. Right now, its difficult to understand what you are trying to query itself.

Comment: select Cart.siteid as siteid, 'Cart accepted' as discountlevel , 'currency' as discounttype , CartRejectedDiscounts.discountid as discountid,
        Cart.auditinfo__createdate as auditinfo__createdate, Cart.auditinfo__updatedate as auditinfo__updatedate
  from CartRejectedDiscounts 
  join 
  Cart 
  ON
  CartRejectedDiscounts._sdc_source_key__id == Cart._id